# How do you create a feature along with linked tasks using PowerShell via the Azure DevOps REST API?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to use PowerShell to call the Azure DevOps API to create a Feature and then create child Tasks that are linked to that Feature.

I have successfully created a Feature; and I have successfully created child Tasks that are linked to said Feature, however, I am not sure how to do it all in one script. The problem I face is that when the child Tasks are created, how do they know the ID of the parent Feature to be linked to, if it is all being done in a single script?

Hope this makes sense.

I have created a Feature and child Tasks to that Feature, but not all done within the same script.

```
#Set some parameters, including the PAT (Personal Access Token) from Azure DevOps

Param (
    [string]$azureDevOpsAccount = "acccount",
    [string]$projectName = "project",
    [string]$workItemType = "Feature",
    [string]$buildNumber = "",
    [string]$keepForever = "true",
    [string]$user = "user",
    [string]$token = "token"
)

#Build the array of tasks
$tasks = @("Task 1","Task 2")

#Iterate over the array
foreach ($task in $tasks)
{
    #Build the JSON body (NOTE: The WorkItem ID needs to be changed in the 'url' property to match the parent WorkItem getting the new tasks. The 'AssignedTo' needs to be validated as well.)
    $body = @"
    [
        {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "from": null,
        "value": "$task"
        },
        {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/relations/-",
        "value": {
            "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
            "url": "https://url/DefaultCollection/project/_apis/wit/workItems/447129"
                 },
        },
        {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.AssignedTo",
        "value": "Person Name"
        }
    ]
"@

    #Required: Convert the PAT to base64
    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

    #Construct the URI
    $uri = "https://$($azureDevOpsAccount).visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/$($projectName)/_apis/wit/workitems/`$Task`?api-version=5.0"

    #Invoke a REST API call for each task to be created
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $body
    $result | ConvertTo-Json
}
```

It creates child Tasks on work item 447129 but I really want my script to create the main Feature and then child Tasks, linked to that Feature and assigned to the person of my choosing via AssignedTo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the Feature with `Invoke-RestMethod` you got a response with details include the `id` of the feature you created:

```
{
     "id": 3124214,
     "rev": 1,
     ... and more
}
```

So just put it in a variable and you can use it when you create the tasks:

```
$newFeature = Invoke-RestMethod ...
$newFeatureId = newFeature.id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't committed to using the REST API directly via Invoke-RestMethod I would recommend using the Azure Devops CLI for this as it will make your scripting a lot simpler and more human-readable.

Once you have it installed the following script will achieve what you are trying to do:

```
$Project = '<YOUR PROJECT>'
$Organization = '<YOUR ORGANIZATION>'
$FeatureID = az boards work-item create --title 'Feature' --type Feature --project $Project --organization $Organization --output json --query 'id'; `
$TaskId = az boards work-item create --title 'Task' --type Task --project $Project --organization $Organization --output json --query 'id'; `
az boards work-item relation add --id $TaskID --relation-type child --target-id $FeatureID --organization $Organization
```